# how can I split a mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

The format of the hg mv command is `hg rename [OPTION]... SOURCE... DEST`
. Path names are relative to the current directory. Thus, when you are at a command prompt at the root directory and specify  `hg mv -n -I * A\B Z`, mercurial will create the directory Z under the root directory, and move A\B\readme.txt to Z\readme.txt.

How can you specify, under Windows, that Z is the repository root directory? I tried using '.' as destination, i.e. `hg mv -n -I * A\B .` but got a message that A\B\readme.txt will be copied to B\readme.txt, not to readme.txt at the root. I tried using '~' as the destination, but  `hg mv -n -I * A\B ~` got me a new directory named "~" below the root, obviously not what I wanted.

So my question is: **How do I specify the repository root directory as the destination to the mercurial move command?**

---

**edit**: I'll try to clarify the issue.

I have an OldDev repository containing two products: Product-A and Product-B. Using the '~' symbol to denote OldDev's root folder, OldDev contains two folders: ~/Product-A and ~/Product-B (in addition, of course, to ~/.hg where its metadata is stored).

Each product is composed of a few projects, and each such project is assigned a folder under the product's folder. Thus Product-A has the Project-A, Project-B and Project-C, stored in  ~/Product-A/Project-A, ~/Product-A/Project-B and ~/Product-A/Project-C, correspondingly. ~/Product-A/Project-A/xxx.cs is one of (Product-A's) Project-A's files.

Now I want to extract Project-A to its own NewDev repository. As it's the single project in NewDev, it makes no sense to retain the product/project hierarchy, so I want it to be at the root of NewDev: it xxx.cs file, for example, will be @/xxx.cs, where @ is the root folder of NewDev (the one contianing NewDev's .hg directory where NewDev's metadata is stored).

To extract Project-A to NewDev I used the the convert extension, as documented in "[split a repository in two](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two)". I used a mapfile containing the one mapping `include Product-A/Project-A`.

So far, NewDev is an exact subtree of OldDev. It does not contain ~/Product-B, it does not contain ~/Product-A/Project-B nor ~/Product-A/Project-C. It only contains ~/Product-A/Project-A. The files that remained are located at exactly the same paths as before, but only those files that belong to Product-A's Project-A were retained.

So, I've achieved half of my goals: I split OldDev, with its many products and projects, and created NewDev with only one project (Project-A). However, the files of Project-A are not at @ but at their old (OldDev) location @/Product-A/Project-A. I need to move them up two steps so xxx.cs, will be at @/xxx.cs and not at @/Product-A/Project-A/xxx.cs

To move the files I tried to use the hg mv command, but I can't figure how to specify the root (@) as the destination.

**Solution**: What worked for me, based on Marc Anton Dahmen's answer, is as follows:

```
convert1.txt: hg convert -s hg -d hg --filemap mapfile1.txt olddev temprepo
mapfile1.txt: include Product-A/Project-A

convert2.txt: hg convert -s hg -d hg --filemap mapfile2.txt temprepo newrepo
mapfile2.txt: rename Product-A/Project-A .
```

Where the text of convrert1.txt and convert2.txt, of course, shell commands.

Comment: Does this answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6725117/1243316

Comment: @BradRem No. It suggests hg move **from** the repository root directory, but does not say how to specify it as the SOURCE in the hg rename command.

Comment: Show that your current directory is really Z. Is that `Z:` or is it `C:\some\directory\named\Z`? What do you think the `-I *` option is supposed to do?

Comment: @msw Z is some directory under the repository root directory and I want it to be the repository root directory. In other words, I want the file [path]RepoRootDir\A\B\x.txt to move two levels up to [path]RepoRootDir\x.txt. -I * means "include all files (i.e. *.*)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the **rename** directive in your filemap instead of **include** like so:

```
rename Project-A .
```

Comment: "You **must** ..., as written in Convert Extension page, ...", sorry

Comment: Thank you - this worked. It needs to be done in two phases, however.

Answer (score 1):

Moving every file in a repository and the repository data is not an `hg mv` operation because that cannot change where the repository meta-data is stored.

The wording of your question is still really ambiguous, but I have a decent guess as to what you want to do.

Suppose you have a repo called /some/dir/avi-repo and you really want it to be in /avi-repo. Use clone:

```
cd /
hg clone /some /avi-repo
```

Now you have two identical copies of the repo, one in `/some/dir/avi-repo` and one in `/avi-repo`. You can delete all of `/some/dir/avi-repo` now.

Your desire seems a little more complicated than that with a tree like:

```
/some
 ---- /.hg  # the repository meta-data
 ---- /dir  # no files in here just the sub-dir
 -------- /avi-repo
 ------------/file.c
 ------------/file.dat
 ------------/important-file.txt
```

And you want to move `avi-repo` to `/some/avi-repo`. You should be able to do that with the right sequence of mercurial commands, but it is far easier to:

```
mkdir /temp
cd /temp
hg clone /some /temp/avi-clone
rm -r /some
mkdir /some
hg clone /temp/avi-clone /some
```

Or some variant of that. The point is that repatriating an entire repository is not a job for `hg mv`.

Comment: I tried to reword it so ti'll be less ambiguous - please see edit above.